# Is there a way to add multiple values for label in nagios/icinga performance data

Tags: performance, nagios, icinga2, icinga

Looks like this is the format for performance data in nagios/icinga

```
'label'=value[UOM];[warn];[crit];[min];[max]
```

Is it possible to add more than one value for single label as shown below?

eg:

```
'label'=value1[UOM],value2[UOM],value3[UOM];[warn];[crit];[min];[max]
```

Or is it possible to rename warn, crit, min, max to value2,value3...???

I would like to get one more column with Value2

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

[This Image is output of performance data from icinga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86JD1.png)

I would like to get one more column with Value2

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it is possible as you can see on figure below where `10`,`11`,`12` are `value1`, `value2` and `value3`:

[image: figure 1]

But main problem here will be graphs and all visualization because they count on define structure of performance data. Data won't be displayed correctly.

Comment: Do you have any link for me to see on how that is achieved?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/86JD1.png

This Image is output of performance data from icinga. I would like to get one more column with Value2

Answer (score 0):

The gold standard for these types of questions is the [Development Guidelines](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html), see the "Performance data" section. It gives this example as "expected format":

`'label'=value[UOM];[warn];[crit];[min];[max]`

It goes on to state that it should contain:

> space separated list of label/value pairs

I don't think this is open for much interpretation: every label has one value, and an optional unit of measurement.